# I'm having difficulty finding a way to track if my character is stationary and what direction they are looking in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently got my character movement working pretty nicely, and I'm now trying to tie it in nicely with the animations I have set up.

**Is there a way to track if the character is stationary?**
*I found a way to track this using:*

```
ani.SetBool("Stationary", rb.IsSleeping());
```

*However, this seems to update pretty slowly for what I need as the character X-Axis keeps updating for about half a second after the movement key is released. Is there a better way to check for a stationary character that will consider the character stationary before it stops fully?*

**Is there a way to track the direction a character is facing and keep them facing that way even if they stop moving?**

Here is my full code for reference;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KittenController2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator ani;

    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;

    private float direction = 0f;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ani = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        direction = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        ani.SetBool("Stationary", rb.IsSleeping());
        
        if (direction > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            ani.SetFloat("Move X", direction);
        }
        else if (direction < 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            ani.SetFloat("Move X", direction);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

    }


    void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        ani.SetTrigger("Jump");
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of direction do you wanna get? Left-Right? Up-Down? Left-Up-Right-Down?

Comment: I'm just looking to get the look direction for left/right for this game!

Comment: Then I am giving you the code soon! I have an old script for the directions! Wait a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsSleeping` is most probably a bad indicator. Afaik a rigidbody goes to sleeping state depending on your physics settings after it has been stationary for a certain delay.

What you rather could use is simply using

```
// In general it is more efficient to check the sqrMagnitude than the magnitude 
// especially if you do it each frame
ani.SetBool("Stationary", Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude, 0));
```

This will simply directly check whether the rigidbody is currently moving.

If a certain movement threshold is precision enough you could also just use

```
[Tooltip ("Below this absolute movement speed the object is considered stationary")]
public float stationaryThreshold = 0.01f;

private float squaredStationaryThreshold;

void Awake()
{
    squaredStationaryThreshold = stationaryThreshold * stationaryThreshold;
}
```

And then check

```
ani.SetBool("Stationary", rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude <= squaredStationaryThreshold);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly and solves both of my issues!

Answer (score 0):

This is for the direction check:

```
private bool facingRight; // serialize this at top
private void FacingRight() // call this in the update function
    {
        if ((facingRight == true) && ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))|| (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)))) // keys you are pressing to move towards left
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
            facingRight = false;
        }
        else if ((facingRight == false) && ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))))) // again the keys you are pressing for the movement to right
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
            facingRight = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this in the morning because I just opened Unity to test it and now my rb.IsSleeping isn't working without me changing anything which is confusing the hell out of me and it's too late to figure it out now!

Comment: But I think using the animator to check if the character is not moving is not a good way. You should find out another way of it. I will also try to do it as fast as possible!